# android openCV watershed

Tags: android, opencv, watershed

I use this code to extract the center segment from an image , But  my code does not work fine and return the input mat as output

```
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR);     
    Marker=new Mat(mRgba.size(),CvType.CV_32S);
    Core.circle(Marker, new Point(mRgba.width()/2,mRgba.height()/2),Math.min(mRgba.width(), mRgba.height()), new Scalar(125,125,125) ,-1);
    Core.circle(Marker, new Point(mRgba.width()/2,mRgba.height()/2),Math.min(mRgba.width()/4, mRgba.height()/4)/4, new Scalar(255,255,255),-1);
    Imgproc.watershed(mRgba , Marker);
    Marker.convertTo(Marker, CvType.CV_8U);

    return Marker;
```